# Не работает запрос UPDATE JSON_SET

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Создаю таблицу через:

```
SELECT pilot_name, hobbies FROM pilot_hobbies;
```

Затем добавила туда данные:

```
INSERT INTO pilot_hobbies
VALUES (
  'Ivan', 
  '{"sports": ["футбол", "плавание"],  "home_lib": true, "trips": 3}' :: json
);
```

Теперь собираюсь обновить скалярное значение по ключу `trips`:

```
UPDATE pilot_hobbies SET
  hobbies = JSON_SET(hobbies, '{trips}', '"10"')
WHERE
  pilot_name = 'Ivan';
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> ОШИБКА:  функция json_set(json, unknown, unknown) не существует
>   LINE 1: UPDATE pilot_hobbies SET hobbies = JSON_SET(hobbies, '{trips...
>   HINT:  Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные преобразования типов.
>   ********** Ошибка **********
>
> ОШИБКА: функция json_set(json, unknown, unknown) не существует
>   SQL-состояние: 42883
>   Подсказка: Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные преобразования типов.
>   Символ: 36

Как правильно сделать на обновлене запрос?

Comment: С каким сервером СУБД вы работаете, и какой версии?

Comment: `'$.trips'`, наверное?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov  делаю в pgAdminIII, версия 9.3., там нет jsonb, на языке T-SQL

Comment: Я спрашиваю о СУБД. Я так понимаю, что это PostgreSQL? Какой версии?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, да, версия 9.3, но в 12 пробовала, таже самая ошибка

Comment: А где вы прочитали о функции `JSON_SET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функции `json_set` для работы с типом `JSON` не
существует.  Существует функция `jsonb_set` для работы
с типом `JSONB`.  Это работает:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pilot_hobbies (
  pilot_name TEXT
, hobbies JSONB
)
;

INSERT INTO pilot_hobbies
  (pilot_name,       hobbies)
VALUES
  (    'Ivan', '{"trips":3}')
;

UPDATE pilot_hobbies SET
  hobbies = jsonb_set(hobbies, '{trips}', '10')
 WHERE
  pilot_name = 'Ivan'
;
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Всё работает! Самое интересное, что у меня пометка : jsonb в версии 9.3 не существует! Вместо jsonb используйте json. Однако, использовав в 12 версии, всё получилось!!! Благодарю!!!